# Closing Terminal without killing command

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I'm starting with Terminal on Mac (OS 10.9.2), and I've got this command which will take a very long time to run. How can I launch this command and then quit the terminal while the command is being carried on i.e. without killing the command?

Just for info, my command finds a certain type of file in my computer then copy it to an external volume.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Would this question be a better fit for http://superuser.com/ where your same account will work?

Comment: This is off-topic and I voted to move it to superuser.com, but the [`screen`](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference) utility is what you'd be looking for. Run `screen`, then start your command there, then do Ctrl+A then D and you can safely close your window. Read the page I've linked for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nohup`:

```
(nohup long-running-command arg1 arg2 … argN) & sleep 1
```

The `sleep 1` gets the message about 'output to `nohup.out`' printed before the next prompt; it is otherwise unnecessary.  This does assume you planned ahead — you knew you'd be running a long-running command.  If you start it off and then find it is taking a long time, you have to look to suspend it (<kbd>Control-Z</kbd>) and then background it (`bg %1`) and `disown` it (that's a Bash built-in command — `disown %1`).